# Docker: permission denied while trying to connect to Docker Daemon with local CircleCI build

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, sudo, circleci

I have a very simple `config.yml`:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/app
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.4.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: node -e "console.log('Hello from NodeJS ' + process.version + '\!')"
      - run: yarn
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run: docker build .
```

All it does: boot a `node` image, test if node is running, do a `yarn install` and a `docker build`.

My dockerfile is nothing special; it has a COPY and ENTRYPOINT.

When I run `circleci build` on my MacBook Air using Docker Native, I get the following error:

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix://[...]`

If I change the `docker build .` command to: `sudo docker build .`, everything works as planned, locally, with `circleci build`.
**However**, pushing this change to CircleCI will result in an error: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

So, to summarize: using `sudo` works, locally, but not on CircleCI itself. **Not** using `sudo` works on CircleCI, but not locally.

Is this something the CircleCI staff has to fix, or is there something I can do?

[For reference, I have posted this question on the CircleCI forums as well.](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/circleci-build-local-machine-fails-when-using-setup-remote-docker)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've created a workaround for myself.

In the very first step of the config.yml, I run this command:

```
if [[ $CIRCLE_SHELL_ENV == *"localbuild"* ]]; then
  echo "This is a local build. Enabling sudo for docker"
  echo sudo > ~/sudo
else
  echo "This is not a local build. Disabling sudo for docker"
  touch ~/sudo
fi
```

Afterwards, you can do this:

```
eval `cat ~/sudo` docker build .
```

### Explanation:

**The first snippet** checks if the CircleCI-provided environment variable `CIRCLE_SHELL_ENV` contains `localbuild`. This is only true when running `circleci build` on your local machine. 
*If true*, it creates a file called `sudo` with contents `sudo` in the home directory.
*If false*, it creates a file called `sudo` with NO contents in the home directory.

**The second snippet** opens the `~/sudo` file, and executes it with the arguments you give afterwards. If the `~/sudo` file contains "`sudo`", the command in this example will become `sudo docker build .`, if it doesn't contain anything, it will become `docker build .`, with a space before it, but that will be ignored.

This way, both the local (`circleci build`) builds and remote builds will work.

Comment: This is a good workaround, but it's too bad their CLI doesn't handle this case...

Comment: I believe your `touch ~/sudo` won't clear the file. It should be `: > ~/sudo` or similar, to actually clear out the file. Essentially it always uses `sudo` since the file never clears.

Comment: @lilone no, every build starts with no `sudo` file. I'm just creating it as an empty file, because otherwise the `eval` would not work.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate on the answer of Jeff Huijsmans,

an alternative version is to use a Bash variable for `docker`:

```
- run:
    name: Set up docker
    command: |
        if [[ $CIRCLE_SHELL_ENV == *"localbuild"* ]]; then
            echo "export docker='sudo docker'" >> $BASH_ENV
        else
            echo "export docker='docker'" >> $BASH_ENV
        fi
```

Then you can use it in your config

```
- run:
    name: Verify docker
    command: $docker --version
```

You can see this in action in [my test for my Dotfiles repository](https://circleci.com/gh/Mandy91/dotfiles/29#config/containers/0)

Documentation about [environment variables in CircleCi](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/)

Answer (score 3):

You might also solve your issue by running the docker image as root. Specify `user: root` under the `image` parameter:

```
...
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/app
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.4.0
        user: root
    steps:
      - checkout
      ...
...
```

Comment: This works but it's heavy-handed and may cause issues for non-trivial setups. In my case, things installed by `pip` ended up under the root user's dirs and thus not being accessible to scripts.

Comment: @Paul you can configure pip to get around that

Comment: ok yeah, but that would just fix one specific case - depending on your setup, many more issues might crop up, currently or in the future, due to the "heavy-handedness" of this... you know?

Comment: @Paul no Im not sure what issues you are referring to. Container is running as root, so it's weaker security, but root is unlimited so I can't see how it would not work. I mean I've never been unable to install something as root that didn't work for root, whereas non-root install will often fail due to missing permissions. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your situation, but that's why in my answer I say "might".